# How to log serial data immediately?

Tags: serial-port, gnu-screen

I am currently working on an electronics project with a microcontroller that sends information over USB to a computer, where it is read from a serial port. I can read the data with screen and log it with stty. The problem I'm having is that the serial port (special file?) doesn't show up in /dev until the device has booted. I manually start screen or stty, and I miss important startup messages.

Is there a way to wait for a serial port to appear, and then to immediately record or view incoming data?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Did you check out `udev` rules yet?

Comment: `udev` allows me to change settings for the connection, but does it allow automatic logging of serial data?

Answer (score 0):

I you know you will be expecting, say, `/dev/ttyUSB0` to appear, you can use the inotify system to wait for it to appear, then do you command:

```bash
inotifywait -m -e create --format %f  /dev |
while read file
do      if [ "$file" = ttyUSB0 ]
        then  cat /dev/ttyUSB0
        fi
done
```

The above prints the basename of each new file (or device) created in the `/dev` directory, eg "ttyUSB0".

---

The create notification is so quick that udev has not yet had time to chgrp the device to group dialout. To wait until that is done, you need to also look for attribute change events as folllows:

```bash
inotifywait -m -e create,attrib --format %f  /dev |
while read file
do      if [ "$file" = ttyUSB0 ]
        then  ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
              group=$(stat --format=%G /dev/ttyUSB0)
              if [ "$group" = dialout ]
              then  cat /dev/ttyUSB0
              fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: I'm getting a permission denied error, even though I am in dialout, and I regularly read from the serial ports. Is this run with a different user?

Comment: This is probably because the notification is so quick that udev has not yet had time to chgrp the device to group dialout. You can either add a small sleep before the cat, or to be deterministic and wait for another notification, this time of the chgrp. Do this with `-e create,attrib`. I saw 2 attribute changes; only the 2nd one had the dialout group change done.